# How to import ApplicationHolder on Grails-4 project?

Tags: grails, plugins

I am upgrading poject from Grails 2 to Grails 4 but I cant import `ApplicationHolder` class.

How can I import the following class in Grails 4 project:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
```

Comment: The answer below addresses the question asked of how you can import it (you can't).  If what you really want is to know how to get a reference to the `GrailsApplication` object, that is a separate question and the answer will depend on from where you want to attain that reference.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I import it on Grails 4 project? org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

You can't.  There is no such class in Grails 4.

I know you didn't ask about this but...

There are a lot of ways to get a reference to the `GrailsApplication` object and which one to use depends on the context in which you want to reference the `GrailsApplication` object.  For example, in any Spring bean that is configured to autowire by name, you can declare a `GrailsApplication grailsApplication` property and that property will be autowired with a reference to the appropriate object.